# install wordpress from zip

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web-services

I have become completely frustrated trying to install WP on my server (hosted at home). I am able to launch the WP content manager and when I find the theme I would like to install, it asks me for my server FTP login. I give it the same logins I use for filezilla but it will not work. I have tried every combination.

So I tried installing from ZIP. I go into "upload" and try to upload the .zip I downloaded from the developer but it takes me again to the FTP login. Same problem as before. The theme I want is called "application" by manshi gori.

[here](http://wordpress.org/themes/application)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way in which you can Disble the FTP Credentials for installing Plugins and Themes from backend

Just Add the following Code in wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Comment: Thansk for the reply. I now get "Could not create directory. /var/www/wp-content/upgrade". Any ideas? I cannot even find the "upgrade" folder there

Comment: Just try to change permission of wp-content folder to 755.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the file permissions:

All files should be 644 and all folders 755.

Comment: permissions have been set. Same issue. Any other ideas? Thanks